# Table is seen twice in sys.tables, once with index and once without

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in Azure SQL Server, and I run the following query to track my DELETE statement.

```
SELECT 
     t.NAME AS TableName,
   i.name as indexName,
    p.[Rows],
    sum(a.total_pages) as TotalPages, 
    sum(a.used_pages) as UsedPages, 
    sum(a.data_pages) as DataPages,
    (sum(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024 as TotalSpaceMB, 
    (sum(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024 as UsedSpaceMB, 
    (sum(a.data_pages) * 8) / 1024 as DataSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND
    i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
 GROUP BY 
    t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name, p.[Rows]
ORDER BY 
    object_name(i.object_id) ;
```

The results shows the table `Events` twice, but once with index and once without.

```
#   TableName   indexName      Rows
1   Events     [NULL]          1,878
2   Events     IX_timestamp    1,886
```

Why I run the following delete statement, it deletes from both tables:

```
DELETE from  [dbo].[Events]
where timestamp >  parse('2021-11-29 08:59:00.1130000' as datetime)
and timestamp < cast('2021-11-30' as date)
```

Can someone please assist in understanding why this happens? I only want the table with the index to exist.

Comment: Rather than having two tables, I'd suggest the more likely answer is that you have two indexes on one table, so are getting two rows. I think the gap in your understanding might be that you have only created one index on `Events`, but every table requires an underlying heap or clustered index, so if you do not define your clustering key, [SQL Server will build a heap index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15), and that is what you are seeing in your first row.

Comment: Thank you @GarethD
I did define a non-clustered index on that table, only. Is that impacting performance in any way?

Comment: Is it impacting performance? Almost certainly. Is it negatively impacting performance? I have no idea but probably. I'd need to know a lot more about the usage of the table to say anything with any degree of conviction, but usually a clustered index will be better than a heap table, even if it is not unique. For an event table, assuming events are inserted as they happen, then I would be inclined to make `timestamp`  a non-unique clustered index, but as I say, at the moment that is a best guess based on assumptions

Comment: If you want to be limited the rows returned from the query you have, the get the size, then limit your results so that only the index with an `ID` of `0` (heap) or `1` (clustered) is returned.

Comment: Looks like a heap with an extra ghost row. Why you have a heap with a non-clustered index is a different question...